# How to use std::find on a vector of array?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am on Ubuntu 14.04, g++ 4.9.3. The code below

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> a;
a.push_back({2, 3, 1});
a.push_back({1, 3, 4});
a.push_back({3, 1, 2});

auto it = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), {2, 3, 1});
```

returns an error

```
couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Tp’
      std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), {2, 3, 1});
                                             ^
```

After a few googling sessions I figured out a more elaborate way to use std::find_if with a lambda function to solve this problem, but why doesn't this code work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to be a little bit more verbose.

```
auto it = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), std::array<int, 3>{2, 3, 1});
```

Verified with gcc 5.3.1. Not sure if your older version of gcc will handle this.

Comment: Wow... it is that simple, I got confused because push_back works without the need of being this verbose. Will accept your answer.

Comment: @user3667089 `push_back` works because its parameter type can be inferred from the type of the expression it's called on.

Comment: In the case of push_back, the `std::initializer_list` parameter type is known, so the initializer list can be deduced directly into the appropriate `std::initializer_list`. It's not that simple with `std::find`, since it's third parameter is a plain template parameter, and not an initializer list; hence it cannot be deduced.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) has no knowledge of `initializer_list`. It works because `push_back` takes a reference to a `T`, and `std::array` can be implicitly constructed from a braced-init-list of the appropriate size. It's simply creating a temporary `array`.